# Request flow when AWS WAF, ALB associated and ALB 4xx

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-waf, 400-bad-request

We have a server configured under a ALB associated with a WAF

> As the underlying service receives requests for your web sites, it forwards those requests to AWS WAF for inspection against your rules. Once a request meets a condition defined in your rules, AWS WAF instructs the underlying service to either block or allow the request based on the action you define.

Above is mentioned in AWS FAQ and according to that I have a understanding that requests first comes to ALB and then forward to WAF.

My questions are in my environment I see some bad requests comes and returns 400 on ALB. they are not counted in WAF so is that mean bad requests are process in ALB? Bad requests are not forwarded to WAF? If I want to forward all the ALB request to WAF is it possible?

Comment: Can you give some examples of requests that don't get forwarded to WAF. And what is your underlying service? EC2? ...?

Comment: yea EC2s under ALB( associated with WAF). ex: Http request for 443, requests without HTTP method ...